# how to access an object in an object by offset?

Tags: javascript, object

OK, I am trying to access an object in a loop for my code to work in every object, unfortunately, my object is located in another object. example:

```
var object = new Object();
object.insider1 = new Object();

object.insider1.name = "ex";
object.insider1.type = "blah";

object.insider2 = new Object();

object.insider2.name = "Ex2";
object.insider2.type = "blah2";
```

Now to access it with the loop:

```
for(var g=0; g<object[object.length]; g++){
//do stuff
}
```

object[object.length] is being noted as 'undefined' and therefore I can't use it... Is there any way to fix this? Thank you!

Comment: You'd use a `for ... in` loop, but JS objects' properties are unordered in nature. You're better off using an array such as Nils' answer.

Answer (score 2):

Looks to me that what you really want is an array property to hold your "insiders". I would do:

```
var object = new Object(); // or simply {}
object.insiders = [];
object.insiders.push({name: "ex", type: "blah"}); 
object.insiders.push({name: "Ex2", type: "Blah2"});
// Or object.insiders.push(insider1) if you have created them already

for(var i = 0; i < object.insiders.length; i++) {
    // Do stuff
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I want, but how will my insider1 and insider2 get the array properies of the array insiders?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. You mean how to put the insiders into the Array? I updated the example.

Comment: Yes but keep their Object properties

Comment: It didn't work for my code :( it worked to push them in but I can't use my objects as objects :S they become arrays... because later on I want to access their information and it's not working

Comment: @user2231784 Inside the loop, use `object.insiders[i].name` and `object.insiders[i].type`.

Comment: The `insiders` property is an array. But the objects inside are regular objects. So instead of having them as `insider1` and `insider2` properties, they are accessed as elements of the array. If your use case is different than this, you should provide som more information.

Comment: my code is huge, but I know the problem is this part because when I have 1 object, everything worked fine,but as soon as I would add an object, the code wouldn't work. So I wrote a loop that woud execute the code for each object individually, and I needed the objects to have array properties. When I tried it using what you said, my code still wouldn't work. If there is a way to send you the code for help it would be great, but I'm sure this is the problem